# Error when I click "Create a Task" under "Activity" while custom lightning component is in the Page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I have created a lightning component. I drag the custom Lightning component from the left side to the desired section of the Opportunity Record Page using Lightning App Builder. I save the changes and activate the new changes. I open the opportunity page my component is there at desired location. But when I click `Create a Task` under `Activity` Tab as shown below [image]

I am getting the following error

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. First, would you give us some details? (We're reporting this as error ID: 132418344)
>
> Uncaught Assertion Failed!: Descriptor for Config required for registration : undefined [Error creating components  in runtime_sales_activities:composerPageBlockSectionEdit]
>   Callback failed: serviceComponent://ui.force.components.controllers.recordLayoutBroker.RecordLayoutBrokerController/ACTION$getLayout
>   throws at https://My-Test-Domain-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/ra1ulv_rPNMd9ZOOtLxgew/aura_prod.js:8:15
>   BH.log()@https://My-Test-Domain-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/ra1ulv_rPNMd9ZOOtLxgew/aura_prod.js:214:393
>   BH.assert()@https://My-Test-Domain-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/ra1ulv_rPNMd9ZOOtLxgew/aura_prod.js:211:43
>   $.B.assert()@https://My-Test-Domain-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/ra1ulv_rPNMd9ZOOtLxgew/aura_prod.js:825:279
>   U.bc()@https://My-Test-Domain-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/ra1ulv_rPNMd9ZOOtLxgew/aura_prod.js:530:88
>   U.vb()@https://My-Test-Domain-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/ra1ulv_rPNMd9ZOOtLxgew/aura_prod.js:556:41
>   U.Od()@https://My-Test-Domain-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/ra1ulv_rPNMd9ZOOtLxgew/aura_prod.js:534:290
>   Object.createComponentFromConfigWithErrorHandling()@https://My-Test-Domain-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/libraries/force/componentLibrary/components.js:6:20

[image]

I don't know whats is going wrong.

Comment: I already have some weird errors too when I had some errors in one my lightning components displayed in a lightning page. The errors raised didn't have anything related to the real error. Did you try to add a basic test lightning component with nothing more than a hello world inside the page? To check if it works?

Comment: @Martin Lezer I made a `hello world` component and It works fine?

Comment: What happens if you insert your custom component inside an empty Lightning application?

Comment: @MartinLezer I inserted in empty lightning app it works fine

Comment: Do you use any external API's which are not listed as compatible with the Lightning Locker Service?

Comment: @MartinLezer  I even tried deactivate every thing in Critical update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65881/discussion-between-ozil-and-martin-lezer).

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the problem, issue was with my external library files, `salesforce` doesn't allow to add `prototype` to`array` data type. Removing that function from `prototype` and making it a separate function resolve my problem.